# DataBase Error while running Asp.NET project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012

This is the error image showing when tried to register to the app:

[image]

This is the register button image:

[image]

I've tried to run my first `Asp.net` project in `visual studio 2015` on my `windows 8.1` PC. But when i was trying to register in the site clicking on the register button, it's showing `SQL Server not found` this type of error. i've uploaded the pic of the error. So, Do i need to install `SQL server` differently with `VS 2015`? or it's already installed by default with VS 2015? Need help from any expert please.

Comment: Your pic has not been uploaded!

Comment: When you upload the pic, could you also give us a little bit more information about how you're connecting etc. Are you using entity framework for example, and could you post any db connection code, thanks

Comment: as i'm new in `Asp.net`, i just created a asp.net mvc application project and visual studio created a default asp.net application. then i tried to register to the application that was created. but it's showing error, when i tried to register.... it's showing that `SQL server not found` exception... what's the problem here actully occuring please let me know?

Comment: I've added the `error message image  link` at first of the description of my post.. please check that..  @Oliver

Comment: Could you head into your web.config file and tell me what is listened in the <ConnectionString> section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem. The `SQL database server` was not installed by default when i installed the `visual studio 2015`. I again modified the `visual studio` with the `database server` and now it's working. Thanks all.